# What is name of a variable within a variable

Tags: regex, variables, powershell

I'm assigning a series of regex's to vars. Some of the regex values will be the same but unique and be identifiable by the var name itself ($a and $c as example).

```
#various regex 
$a = "([\d]{1,2})"
$b = "([\d]{3})"
$c = $b #Note this has the same regex as $b 
$d = "\s[-]\s"
$e = "[_]"

#select the pattern
$patternNum = 4
```

I then want to be able to concat the vars in different orders to create a larger regex.

```
Switch ($patternNum){

#create a pattern
1 { $pattern = ($a, $e, $b) }
2 { $pattern = ($a, $d, $b) }
3 { $pattern = ($a, $d, $a, $e, $b) }
4 { $pattern = ($a, $e, $b, $e, $c) }

}
```

This creates the expanded regex string i'm hoping for

```
#so i can use full regex pattern later
$selectedPattern = -join $pattern
```

But I want to be able to associate the var in $pattern with the original var name and not the literal string that's associated with the var (as some strings will be the same)

```
#find the index of each var and assign to another var so var can be used later to identify position within match 
var1 = [array]::IndexOf($pattern, $a) # [0]
var2 = array]::IndexOf($pattern, $b) # [2]
var3 = [array]::IndexOf($pattern, $c) # [2] but i want it to be [4]
```

The regex which will be used in matching, each match will be used in different strings and in different positions

I thought i'd be able to use scriptblock {} and then convert back to string but that doesn't seem to work. Can anybody think of a way to get each vars original var name or think of a better way of doing this?

Comment: How about using named captures in the regexes, and match those to the variable names?

Comment: Sorry fairly new to scripting and horrible at regex. I'm doing a little ps for my self and a few family members and friends to mass update mp3 file names and idtags. for me i can create regex to me my needs, for them i want to be able to give them a template and be able create there own so this would have to be able to be dynamic.      $selectedPattern = "^($varTrack$varSpace$varYear$varSpace$varArtist$varSpace$varAlbum$varSpace$varTitle)$" }                                   $selectedPattern = "^($varTrack$varSpace$varArtist$varSpace$varTitle)$" }

Comment: Do you know how to use a named capture in a regex?

Comment: I wish that i could say i did:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using named captures

Use (? ) syntax to create named captures.  Make the name the same as your variable names, e.g.:

```
$A = '(?<A>\d{3})'
$B = '(?<B>\D{3})'

$string = 'ABC123'

$regex = $B + $A

$string -match $regex

$Matches

Name                           Value                                                             
----                           -----                                                             
A                              123                                                               
B                              ABC                                                               
0                              ABC123
```

Now you can correlate the variables to the position they matched in the string like this:

```
$string.IndexOf($Matches.A)
3

$string.IndexOf($Matches.B)
0
```

Comment: Awesome, I was actually just in the process of reading your article, when i noticed your reply. Yeah this is the way i'm gonna go. I am now running into a bit of snag...the indexes being returned are -1. I'm guessing its just syntax. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

following your code I'll do it like this, but knowing what's is your real need someone can suggest other solution:

```
$c = $b 
$d = "\s[-]\s"
$e = "[_]"

#select the pattern
$patternNum = 4

Switch ($patternNum){

#create a pattern
1 { $pattern = ('$a', '$e', '$b') }
2 { $pattern = ('$a', '$d', '$b') }
3 { $pattern = ('$a', '$d', '$a', '$e', '$b') }
4 { $pattern = ('$a', '$e', '$b', '$e', '$c') }

}

$selectedPattern = -join $pattern

$var1 = [array]::IndexOf($pattern, '$a') # [0]
$var2 = [array]::IndexOf($pattern, '$b') # [2]
$var3 = [array]::IndexOf($pattern, '$c') # [4] 

#converting literal to your pattern
$regexpattern = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString( -JOIN $pattern )

$regexpattern
([\d]{1,2})[_]([\d]{3})[_]([\d]{3})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, thats actually what the result is now, i'm hoping to be able to get the opposite get back either a string or an array of the original variable names (e.g [string]$pattern = $a$b$c$d$e / $pattern [array] = ($a,$b,$c$d,$e) )